# Creating a for loop with an embedded if statement

Tags: excel, for-loop, if-statement

I would like one sheet to reference another, thats ez.
First sheet has credit card statements on it
Second sheet needs to look at first sheet and look at the date ranges, for each date it should check to see if it is the date in the A column of the 2nd sheet. 
If it is the correct date it should add that amount to column B of the 2nd sheet.

So in a real basic coding language it would look like this

```
B1 = 0
For Sheet1!A1 to Sheet1!A99(If Sheet1!A1 = Sheet2!A1 then Sheet2!B1 + Sheet1!B2)
```

I just want to know if this is possible in excel or if i'm going to be doing all this by hand, which would make me sad.

Comment: I am sure that this can be accomplished with vba and/or formulas.  But Stack Overflow is not a code for me, teach me to code, or show me where to start site.  Please put any code you have tried and explain where it fails and ask a specific question pertaining to that failure.

Comment: In say `C1`, `=If($A1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!B1+Sheet2!B2,"")` and drag down?

Comment: unfortunatly some days there are no charges and some days there are 10+ charges. I need the program to differentiate that. Pulling the above down will just lead to a bunch of blanks.

Comment: So you need a formula in Sheet2!B1:Bn that looks in Sheet1!A1:A999 for the date in Sheet2!A1:An and if it finds it displays the amount from column B in that row in Sheet1?  That's what VLOOKUP does - you just need to put this in Sheet2!B1.  `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$999,2,0)`  And then copy it down to all the other rows on Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that the SUMIF function can accomplish?